# Getting the record with latest record on join order by date

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, ssms

Consider two tables like this

```
id  name 
1   john  
2   doe
3   jan

device id   id  devicename     purchasedate
1           1    iphone         2018-02-22
2           1    iphone2        2019-02-22  
3           1    iphone3        2020-02-22
4           2    iphone4        2019-02-22
5           2    iphone5        2019-02-25
6           3    iphone6        2020-03-15
```

So the result must be the join of the two tables and only the latest purchased date of a record must be selected. So the expected select result will be like this and if there is a record in the first table with no relationship in the second table, it should not be selected so only inner join can be used.

```
id name device id device name 
1  john    3        iphone3
2  doe     5        iphone5
3  jan     6        iphone6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `cross apply`:

```
select t1.name, t2.* -- or whatever columns you want
from table1 t1 cross apply
     (select top (1) t2.*
      from table2 t2
      where t2.id = t1.id
      order by t2.purchaseddate desc
     ) t2
```

Comment: Is there any possible way to avoid two selects and get the same result? As having two selects is a costly operation.

Comment: @VamsiShankar . . . Your comment is a little confusing.  You have two tables.  Your query needs to reference both of them.  This should be quite performant compared to other methods -- assuming you have an index on `table2(id, purchasedate desc0`.